# SQLServer make summary of N records from set of M records

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I'm using sql server and I want to achieve the following:

I have M number of records in the database and I want to take N records summarising the M records.

> Here is an example:
>
> M = 1000; 
>   N = 100;
>
> I want to take 100 records from those 1000 but the 100 records should
>   be from 0 to 1000   (e.g. 0th record, 10th record, 20th record, 30th
>   record... 990 record, 1000 record) so I can draw a chart for them.

What is the best way to achieve this with a sql query.

Thank you in adance.

Comment: **summarising the M records.** means??

Comment: Use mod operator (%). `SELECT 'foo' FROM bar WHERE M % N = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `ROW_NUMBER()` and modulus division:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) RowNum 
      FROM  YourTable
      )sub
WHERE RowNum <= 1000    --M if it's a variable
  AND RowNum % (1000/100) = 0  -- M/N if they're variables
```

If you already have a counter, like an `INTEGER` ID field, it's even easier:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID <= 1000
  AND ID % (1000/100) = 0
```

Comment: +1, but I think 10 should be changed on smth like 1000 / 100 (actually M / N) ?

Comment: @RomanPekar yeah I wondered if they might be variables, altered answer slightly.

Comment: may be also change < 1000 to <= 1000?